# Java - How do I get a variable generated from within a method in one class to another class?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I'm still quite the novice to Java, so please forgive the myriad of noob mistakes about to be laid before you. 
So I'll clarify. A variable is generated from within a method based on an array.

```
public class Track {
    public final int[] classN = { 5, 1 };
    public final int[] classD = { 10, 1 };
    public final int[] classC = { 15, 2 };
    public final int[] classB = { 20, 2 };
    public final int[] classA = { 25, 3 };
    public final int[] classS = { 30, 3 };
    public final int[] classSS = { 50, 3 };
    public final int[][] arTrackClass = { classN, classD, classC, classB, classA, classS, classSS };
    public static final String[] arNameClass = { "N", "D", "C", "B", "A", "S", "SS" };

    public int trackLength = 5; //I need to put it outside of the modifier to get anything else to access it.

    public void getRaceClass() {
        int tClass = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*arTrackClass.length));
        trackLength = arTrackClass[tClass][0];  //This is the important bit for elsewhere
        tMaxDiff = arTrackClass[tClass][1];
        String nameClass = arNameClass[tClass];
        System.out.println("The track will be a " + nameClass + " class race with " + trackLength + " lengths.");

    }
}
```

So this is what I am using to generate how long the track is. From 5 up to 50 lengths. This is no problem and works fine for me. The bit of issue comes when I try and call trackLength later to tell my for loop how many times to loop when it draws the graph.

```
public class Graph {

    public drawGraph() {
        for ( int i=0; i<=Track.trackLength; i++ ) {
            //Code
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my main class, no matter what I do, I cannot get trackLength in drawGraph() to equal the generated trackLength in getRaceClass().

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Track track = new Track();
        track.getRaceClass()

        Graph graphing = new Graph();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                graphing.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If there needs to be any more info let me know and I'll provide as much as I can. 
I just really need to to call on the variable after it has been generated. Or if anyone else has an idea I'm always for listening to the more experienced.

Comment: In your `Graph` class do you ever create an instance or an object of `Track`? Something like `Track myTrack = new Track()`. From what you have posted it looks like you make one in `Main` that you may want to pass into `graphing` via a constructor parameter.

Comment: Pass the reference of `Track` to `Graph`...

Comment: Yes, but even then it calls the pre-set trackLength that I had to initialize for external access, rather than the one generated after getTrackClass()

Comment: Are you sure you method `getRaceClass()` isn't just setting the variable to the same value as the one you set initially? For example, if you change `public int trackLength = 5;` to `public int trackLength = 50;` do you still get similar results?

Comment: Yes, if I change the value of trackLength manually, it generates the differently sized graphs as it should. That's why I have it print the trackClass and randomly selected Length to console, for debugging reasons. If it calls for a SS race which has a length of 50, it'll still only write 5 loops to the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply `Graph` with the instance of `Track` it is going to be working with...

```
public class Graph extends ... {
    private Track track;
    //...
    public Graph(Track track) {
        //...
        this.track = track;
        //...
```

Then when `Graph` needs information from `Track`, it can simple use `track`

```
public drawGraph() {
    for ( int i=0; i<=track.trackLength; i++ ) {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Then, you would simply pass the reference of an instance of `Track` to `Graph`, for example...

```
Track track = new Track();
track.getRaceClass()

Graph graphing = new Graph(track);
```